# Moving site from one environment to another

Tags: migrations

I have a Drupal 8 site installed on a staging server. When moving on the production server,  I do a `git pull`, import the database and the site is there and working. I do the same after some configuration is changed,I do a `git pull` and the usual `drush cim`, but I get:

> Cannot change the install profile from to standard once Drupal is installed.

How do I get around this?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2870028

Comment: make this an answer and I'll chose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your settings.local.php (or settings.php if you don't have one) for 'install_profile' and make sure this is set and matches your staging environment:

https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/2e8b29651cfb08309098c239ce9d03e724d747b3/sites/default/default.settings.php#L279

If that doesn't work you can take a look at https://www.drupal.org/node/2870028 as @jaypan said